# 19.10 How can I keep my Logitech MX Master connected after suspension?

Tags: bluetooth, 19.10, logitech

I just purchased a Logitech MX Master mouse that connects via Bluetooth; my PC has a Broadcom BCM20702A0 Bluetooth adapter. Everything works great but if the PC falls asleep or if I set it to suspend, when I turn everything back on the mouse isn't connected and I have to disconnect/connect again before it will work again. I also tried installing blueman and that didn't work either. Is there any way to prevent this problem?

Edit: to answer the questions from the comments

1. Ubuntu 19.10
2. MX Master, not MX Master 3.
3. When I ran "lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && lsusb" it came back blank, so here's my full lspci adn lsusb:

lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [8086:3ec2] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 8th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [1462:7b48]
    Kernel driver in use: skl_uncore
    Kernel modules: ie31200_edac
00:01.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) [8086:1901] (rev 07)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 System peripheral [0880]: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [8086:1911]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model [1462:7b48]
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [8086:a2af]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller [1462:7b48]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:14.2 Signal processing controller [1180]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem [8086:a2b1]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH Thermal Subsystem [1462:7b48]
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH CSME HECI #1 [8086:a2ba]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH CSME HECI [1462:7b48]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:17.0 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode] [8086:a282]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH SATA controller [AHCI mode] [1462:7b48]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #1 [8086:a290] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH PCI Express Root Port #4 [8086:a293] (rev f0)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller [8086:a2c9]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Z370 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller [1462:7b48]
00:1f.2 Memory controller [0580]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller [8086:a2a1]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family Power Management Controller [1462:7b48]
00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 200 Series PCH HD Audio [8086:a2f0]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series PCH HD Audio [1462:9b48]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1f.4 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:a2a3]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] 200 Series/Z370 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [1462:7b48]
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] [10de:1b80] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] [1458:3717]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: NVIDIA Corporation GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [10de:10f0] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd GP104 High Definition Audio Controller [1458:3717]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 15)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:7b48]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1b48 Corsair CORSAIR STRAFE RGB MK.2 Mechanical Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: To start, 1) which version of Linux is installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.),  2) Do you have the MX Master https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360024154914 or MX Master 3  https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360035271133 ?   3) Please also run _lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 && lsusb -v_ then copy the resulting text, return here, click [edit], & paste resulting text into question. Please don't Add Comment. That's our channel to you. All facts about yr system should go in the Question with [edit]